# Can we use "best man" without an article?

Tags: articles

I was best man at a friend's wedding.
Can we use "best man" without an article? Thanks.

Comment: I would say yes, because it works like a title, and titles don't normally take articles (like "She is Queen") but I'll let somebody else give a more detailed answer.

Comment: As other answers have said, you can omit the article. I just wanted to add: you can also leave it in. In other words: "I was best man at Jacob's wedding" is correct, but that doesn't mean "I was _the_ best man at Jacob's wedding" is wrong.

Comment: Some related questions and answers: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/64671/ http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24921/ http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69759/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct without *a* or *the* because there is only one best man at a wedding. You can do that same thing for similar nouns: *He was captain of the football team.* *She was chess champion of the world.* *I was president of the debating club*.

But if there can be more than one with the same title, you would use *a* or *the*. I was *a* groomsman at my friend's wedding. (Not: I was groomsman.) She was *a* vice-president of the company.  See [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/298762/153649).

Although to me, we can say *He was co-captain of the football team* even when there are more than one co-captains.

See [Can predicative complements not be bare noun phrases in English? That is, are clauses such as “I am student” incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268282/can-predicative-complements-not-be-bare-noun-phrases-in-english-that-is-are-cl).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, colloquially, I hear this type of statement often.
While most commonly you would say "I was the best man at a friend's wedding.", colloquially, I have often heard it said without the article. Spoken speech is often more informal than when it is written.

This omission of articles has also been addressed here;
[When can an article be omitted?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/when-can-an-article-be-omitted)